# Query for documents to iterate over Array and take sum on a particular property of JSON in mongodb using $cond

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have a array of `JSON` like this:

```
let x = [{"Data":"Chocolate","Company":"FiveStar"},{"Data":"Biscuit","Company":"Parle"},{"Data":"Chocolate","Company":"DairyMilk"}]
```

This is a sample array of `JSON`. What I want to do is how to use MongoDB `$cond` to take count of all fields having  "Data" equals Chocolate?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stick to `$cond` then you could run the query like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      Data: "Chocolate"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Data",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$Data",
                "Chocolate"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

You can see the results of this query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yy_9m31n8Hu).

---

You can see that firstly I get all elements where `Data` is equal to "Chocolate" with [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Later, we can use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to get a count of the elements that match the conditions with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and return `1` if it is equal and `0` if not.

In this case, we only are left with the `Data` that is equal to "Chocolate" anyway.

---

Of course, it would be faster and easier to simply run:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      Data: "Chocolate"
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
])
```

The example of this query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dker3UT2vyO).

Comment: My problem is  I don't want to match on data chocolate since I have 6 to 7 different counts based on other fields in mongodb . Can we apply $match inside $cond or some other solution inside $group?This x1 is a field inside mongodb

Comment: What is your expected putput

Comment: It would be ideal if you provided more information in your question by editing it. If you removed `$match` from the first example it would still work, but then you will get the entire array of data with the count specified in `$cond`. You can test it yourself by following the link to the code that I have provided.

Comment: Now you came to point ,what I want to do is to iterate over this Array   inside $cond and then take count of all fields having Data Chocolate

Comment: `$cond` has a specific syntax that you can read more about here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/ It is basically `if-else` condition. If you explained exactly what is the expected output, then possibly we can find a solution. As of now, I am not sure whether I understand your issue. Based on your sample data, we already have a count of all the fields where `Data` is equal to "Chocolate".